# coverting column to row using my sql

Tags: mysql

**i have following mysql query:**

```
SELECT 
    a.id, a.sbu_name, b.month,b.week, b.DateRange, b.planned
FROM
    (SELECT 
        id, sbu_name
    FROM
        tbl_sbu) a
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        sbu_id,
            month,
            WEEK(month) week,
            CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(month, INTERVAL (1 - DAYOFWEEK(month)) DAY), '%Y-%m-%e'), ' TO ', DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(month, INTERVAL (7 - DAYOFWEEK(month)) DAY), '%Y-%m-%e')) AS DateRange,
            SUM(amount) / 100000 AS planned
    FROM
        tbl_collection_planed
    WHERE
        DATE_FORMAT(month, '%Y-%m') = '2016-08'
    GROUP BY DateRange) b ON b.sbu_id = a.id order by week asc
```

**The output of above query is:** [image: image of current output]

I want my output as follows:
[image: image of wanted result]

Comment: So you manually type in "2016-08" ?

Comment: IT WOUD BE A FILTER OF DATE WHICH I WILL GIVE TO USER TO SELECT for demo purpose i have put month manually

Comment: Please stop shouting

Comment: I'm not aware of the concept of filters in MySQL

Comment: So, handle the display logic in the front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a table pivot question, if just for this case, you can try following query;)

```
SELECT 
    sbu_name,
    IF(DateRange = '2016-08-7 TO 2016-08-13', planned, '') AS `2016-08-7 TO 2016-08-13`,
    IF(DateRange = '2016-08-14 TO 2016-08-20', planned, '') AS `2016-08-14 TO 2016-08-20`,
    IF(DateRange = '2016-08-21 TO 2016-08-27', planned, '') AS `2016-08-21 TO 2016-08-27`,
    IF(DateRange = '2016-08-28 TO 2016-09-3', planned, '') AS `2016-08-28 TO 2016-09-3`
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.id, a.sbu_name, b.month,b.week, b.DateRange, b.planned
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            id, sbu_name
        FROM
            tbl_sbu) a
            LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT 
            sbu_id,
                month,
                WEEK(month) week,
                CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(month, INTERVAL (1 - DAYOFWEEK(month)) DAY), '%Y-%m-%e'), ' TO ', DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(month, INTERVAL (7 - DAYOFWEEK(month)) DAY), '%Y-%m-%e')) AS DateRange,
                SUM(amount) / 100000 AS planned
        FROM
            tbl_collection_planed
        WHERE
            DATE_FORMAT(month, '%Y-%m') = '2016-08'
        GROUP BY DateRange) b ON b.sbu_id = a.id order by week asc
) t
GROUP BY sub_name
```

If this `DateRange` has dynamic values, you have to do this with a dynamic sql.

**EDITED(dynamic sql)**

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(DateRange = ''',
      CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(month, INTERVAL (1 - DAYOFWEEK(month)) DAY), '%Y-%m-%e'), ' TO ', DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(month, INTERVAL (7 - DAYOFWEEK(month)) DAY), '%Y-%m-%e')),
      ''', planned, '')) AS `',
      CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(month, INTERVAL (1 - DAYOFWEEK(month)) DAY), '%Y-%m-%e'), ' TO ', DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(month, INTERVAL (7 - DAYOFWEEK(month)) DAY), '%Y-%m-%e')), '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM tbl_collection_planed
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(month, '%Y-%m') = '2016-08'
;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT sbu_name, ', @sql, ' FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.id, a.sbu_name, b.month,b.week, b.DateRange, b.planned
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            id, sbu_name
        FROM
            tbl_sbu) a
            LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT 
            sbu_id,
                month,
                WEEK(month) week,
                CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(month, INTERVAL (1 - DAYOFWEEK(month)) DAY), \'%Y-%m-%e\'), \' TO \', DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(month, INTERVAL (7 - DAYOFWEEK(month)) DAY), \'%Y-%m-%e\')) AS DateRange,
                SUM(amount) / 100000 AS planned
        FROM
            tbl_collection_planed
        WHERE
            DATE_FORMAT(month, \'%Y-%m\') = \'2016-08\'
        GROUP BY DateRange) b ON b.sbu_id = a.id order by week asc
) t
GROUP BY sub_name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: daterange has dynamic values. can u plz help me out for this i have tried but could not make it

Comment: yes it is working but my datrange has dynamic values i m stuck here only

Comment: @Nitin Check the **edited** answer for dynamic values please.

Comment: :( its throwing an error:    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
to use near '2016-08-7', planned, ')) AS `2016-08-7`,MAX(IF(DateRange = '2016-08-21', 
planned' at line 1 0.000 sec

Comment: same error which i have mentioned above occuring :(                                        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
 to use near '2016-08-7', planned, ')) AS `2016-08-7`,
 MAX(IF(DateRange = '2016-08-21', planned' at line 1 0.000 sec

Comment: thank u very much really apprecited i got my result ...:)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
**select * from (**
SELECT 
a.id, a.sbu_name, b.month,b.week, b.DateRange, b.planned
FROM
    (SELECT 
    id, sbu_name
    FROM
    tbl_sbu) a
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
    sbu_id,
        month,
        WEEK(month) week,
        CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(month, INTERVAL (1 -  DAYOFWEEK(month)) DAY), '%Y-%m-%e'), ' TO ', DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(month,  INTERVAL (7 - DAYOFWEEK(month)) DAY), '%Y-%m-%e')) AS DateRange,
        SUM(amount) / 100000 AS planned
    FROM
    tbl_collection_planed
    WHERE
    DATE_FORMAT(month, '%Y-%m') = '2016-08'
    GROUP BY DateRange) b ON b.sbu_id = a.id **) as b group by DateRange**
```